# Can not load any gems after upgrade

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to move from ruby 1.8 to 1.9 something.

I have tried installing the newer ruby in a number of ways - with rvm, with apt-get, etc. No matter which way I do it, once I've got /usr/bin/ruby pointing at that, no gems can be loaded ("no such file to load").

I have tried reinstalling them, both as super user and regular, and the gem install command finishes successfully, but it still doesn't find them.

I have also installed rubygems1.9.1

Can someone please tell me what's wrong. This is insanely frustrating - I have installed every gem several times in many many places and yet it doesn't find any of them. I have tried setting GEMS_DIR to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove every Ruby installation you got. Be sure there are no 'ruby' and 'gem' executables anywhere.
2. Install RVM and check if it went well
3. Install all the dependencies listed in `rvm notes` output.
4. Do `rvm install 1.9.2` and start installing your gems.

Comment: No luck, I've already tried doing this. RVM doesn't really seem to work for me... 'rvm use 1.9.2' says that's its using that version, but I can't really tell what it does. It _doesn't_ link that executable to /usr/bin/ruby, which seems like a pretty crucial step, so I'm not sure what else, if anything, it is doing. I've tried doing rvm gem install ______, sudo rvm gem install (which the docs say not to), and regular [sudo] gem install. It doesn't matter, when I try to run a script with gems it fails to load them.

Comment: `rvm use` should not link to /usr/bin/ruby, everything should be happening inside your home dir.

Comment: @hsiu, It really sounds like you need to take the time to read completely through the [installation documents](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) for RVM, including the "Post Install" and troubleshooting section before you start.

Comment: step 3 should be to confirm the RVM install using the "Post Install" section of the install page. Step 4 should be to follow the directions after typing `rvm notes`. Then RVM can be used to install Rubies.